# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'

Tags: javascript, error-handling, drupal-7

http://tristarprotector.com/temp/I've seen others posted about this but the answers don't make sense to me.

I'm getting this error when I debugg in IE9 and IE8

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'
File: pluigns.js, Line: 19, Column: 207

This is what line 19 says:

```
"auto":"pan-y";$menu.css("ms-touch-action",touchAction)},applyHandlers=function($menu,o){var targets="li:has("+o.popUpSelector+")";if($.fn.hoverIntent&&!o.disableHI)$menu.hoverIntent(over,out,targets);else $menu.on("mouseenter.superfish",targets,over).on("mouseleave.superfish",targets,out);var touchevent="MSPointerDown.superfish";if(!ios)touchevent+=" touchend.superfish";if(wp7)touchevent+=" mousedown.superfish";$menu.on("focusin.superfish","li",over).on("focusout.superfish","li",out).on(touchevent,
```

and [a link to the page](http://tristarprotector.com/temp/)

Comment: Run the debugger so it will break on that line and then you can look at what `$menu` is and look up the call stack to see why it isn't set properly.  Are you, by any chance, using jQuery 2.x which doesn't support older versions of IE?

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel this question needed to be voted down but I don't know what you mean by 'look at what $menu is and look up the call stack to see why it isn't set properly' I am using jQuery jquery.js?v=1.4.4, not sure if that could be the culprit.

Comment: I'd recommend you do a search on how to open and use the debugger in IE (you will probably need to learn that to solve this problem).  The problem is likely caused before this particular line of code so you will have to be able to see the context of what is being executed at the time of the error and the debugger is the tool for that.  We are unlikely to be able to guess what the problem is here.

Comment: As your question stands now, there is insufficient information for anyone to even guess what the problem is.  That is probably why it has been downvoted.  You haven't taken the normal debugging steps that would be required to gather information on a problem like this.

Comment: I know how to open and view code using the IE debugger tool, just wasn't sure what to do after finding the line 19 code with the problem. Turns out there was no problem with that line of code at all, I just had to update my version of jQuery and now it works fine all the way down to IE7 even. Thanks for your suggestion and help!

Comment: I'd suggest you either close your question or post your own answer (you can answer your own questions) so everyone knows this question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the error was that I needed an updated version of jQuery installed.

I updated to jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2